# Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtService (?). Please make sure that the argument JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS

Tags: nodejs, typescript, jwt

estoy siguiendo la documentacion de nest js para hacer la autenticacion (https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication) y me sale este error.

```
Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JwtService (?). Please make sure that the argument JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS at index [0] is available in the AppModule context.

Potential solutions:
- If JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS is a provider, is it part of the current AppModule?
- If JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS is exported from a separate @Module, is that module imported within AppModule?
  @Module({
    imports: [ /* the Module containing JWT_MODULE_OPTIONS */ ]
  })
```

Mi app.module.ts

```
    @Module({
      imports: [
        CustomerModule,
        TypeOrmModule.forRoot(dbconfig),
        AuthModule,
        UserModule
      ],
      controllers: [AppController],
      providers: [AppService, UserService , AuthService , JwtService],
    })
    export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: Como estas, pudiste solucionarlo? tengo el mismo problema.

Answer (score 0):

Me estaba ocurriendo lo mismo, resulta que el error se da cuando se usa el nombre del modelo diferente en el servicio cuando lo inyectas con el que tienes en el módulo:

En este caso de ejemplo, el modelo: **User**, que usas en el servicio, se debe llamar igual al que importas en el Módulo, *TypeOrmModule.forFeature*, cualquier variación en el nombre de esta como: **Users** o similar te dará ese error, dejo un ejemplo:

user.service.ts

```
constructor(@InjectRepository(User) private usersRepository: Repository<User> ){}
```

user.module.ts

```
@Module({
 imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User])],
 providers: [...],
 controllers: [...],
})
```

Te dejo la página de referencia de la [documentación](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database)

Answer (score 0):

Me estaba ocurriendo lo mismo justo hace rato, logre solucionarlo quitando *JwtService* de **providers** y agregando el *JwtModule* (ya sea con `.register()` o `.regirterAsync()`) a **imports**.

Answer (score 0):

actualice la importación. simplemente agregue JwtModule.register({}) en la importación funciona bien en mi caso

```
  imports: [TypeOrmModule.forFeature([User,UserRepository]),JwtModule.register({})],
```